# Measure multiple properties?

Tags: powershell, measure, get-childitem, powershell-5.1

I'd like to query a directory with Get-ChildItem and create a table with columns like Path, Size(in Gb), MinimumCreationTime, MaximumCreationTime. In foreach cycle I wrote 3 Measure commands. Is it possible Measure multiple properties with one command?

```
$pathes = @'
C:\open
C:\games
'@.Split([System.Environment]::NewLine, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

foreach ($path in $pathes){
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Measure Length -Sum 
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Measure CreationTime -Minimum
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Measure CreationTime -Maximum
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible with a single call to the `Measure-Object` command, using a calculated property that converts the `CreationTime` property to numeric type. Now `-Sum` can work with that (albeit we'll discard the sum for `CreationTime`).

After we've calculated the stats, we convert back to `[DateTime]` to get meaningful display values.

Since PS 7+, a calculated property can be used as `Measure-Object` argument. For older PS versions, we can use `Select-Object` to create a calculated property.

### PS 7+ solution

```
foreach ($path in $pathes){

    $stats = Get-ChildItem $path -File -Recurse | 
             Measure-Object 'Length', { $_.CreationTime.Ticks } -Sum -Minimum -Maximum

    # Create the output for one table row
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Path                = $path
        'Size(GB)'          = [math]::Round( $stats[0].Sum / 1GB, 2 )   # 2 = number of digits
        MinimumCreationTime = [DateTime] [Int64] $stats[1].Minimum
        MaximumCreationTime = [DateTime] [Int64] $stats[1].Maximum
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- We are specifying two properties in the call to `Measure-Object`:

  - 1st property is just `Length`
  - 2nd property is a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1), meaning it gets its value from running a small script block. The script block converts the `CreationTime` to `Int64` and uses it as value that will be measured.
- When specifying multiple properties for `Measure-Object`, it outputs an array that contains an object for each property, which contains the stats.

  - `$stats[0]` contains the `Sum`, `Minimum` and `Maximum` for the `Length` property, of which we only take the `Sum`.
  - `$stats[1]` contains the `Sum`, `Minimum` and `Maximum` for the `CreationTime` property, of which we only take the `Minimum` and `Maximum`. Note that `Measure-Object` produces output of type `[double]`, so we first have to convert back to `[Int64]` before finally converting back to `[DateTime]`.

### PS 5 solution

```
foreach ($path in $pathes){

    $stats = Get-ChildItem $path -File -Force | 
        Select-Object Length, @{ name = 'CreationTimeTicks'; expression = { $_.CreationTime.Ticks } } | 
        Measure-Object Length, CreationTimeTicks -Sum -Minimum -Maximum

    # Create the output for one table row - identical to PS 7+ solution
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Path                = $path
        'Size(GB)'          = [math]::Round( $stats[0].Sum / 1GB, 2 )   # 2 = number of digits
        MinimumCreationTime = [DateTime] [Int64] $stats[1].Minimum
        MaximumCreationTime = [DateTime] [Int64] $stats[1].Maximum
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

This is similar to the PS 7+ solution, except that we use `Select-Object` to create a calculated property named `CreationTimeTicks`, so we can pass it by name to the `Measure-Object` call.

### Conclusion

While this code appears to work, the code presented by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66697656/7571258) is conceptually much clearer, so I would go with it.

Comment: Error: The property " $_.CreationTime.Ticks " cannot be found in the input for any objects.

Comment: @user2978216 Have you specified parameter `-File` for `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: No, I just copied your code. Do I need to put something there?

Comment: @zett42 `Measure-Object` was only recently updated to accept property expressions (7.x), prior to that (including in all versions of WPS) it only accepts strings - so it only supports named properties, not calculated ones

Comment: Added a PS 5 solution using `Select-Object` to define a calculated property.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible Measure multiple properties with one command?

Yes you can - *just not the way you need it to*.

The reason we can't quite consolidate all three invocations here is that `Measure-Object` will perform *all requested calculations* on *each input property* - and it can't meaningfully calculate the sum of multiple `[datetime]` values.

So at best, we can do it with only 2 rounds of piping to `Measure-Object`:

```
$paths = 'C:\open','C:\games'

foreach ($path in $paths){
    # Let's call Get-ChildItem ONCE, and store the result
    $children = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse 

    # Now let's do our calculations
    $fileSize = $children | Measure Length -Sum 
    $newAndOld = $children | Measure CreationTime -Minimum -Maximum

    # And finally create a new object to hold the details we calculated above
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Path           = $path
      TotalSize      = $fileSize.Sum
      OldestFileTime = $newAndOld.Minimum
      NewestFileTime = $newAndOld.Maximum
    }
}
```

PowerShell will default to table-format when displaying objects with 4 or fewer properties, so you can expect the default output in the shell to be something like this (depending on locale):

```
Path      TotalSize OldestFileTime       NewestFileTime
----      --------- --------------       --------------
C:\open  1234567890 1/1/2018 2:00:00 AM  1/31/2021 7:45:00 PM
C:\games 1234567890 1/1/2018 2:00:00 AM  1/31/2021 7:45:00 PM
```